# Custom Data Type returning as an Json Object in umbraco

Tags: c#, angularjs, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

i am trying to create a carousel as a Data Type,
for that i am trying to create a custom Data Type like this from Developers Tab

[image]

in content section it will show like this

[image]

so am calling this new Datatype in Templates like this

[image]

but i am getting in browser the entire object like this

[image]

the response is like this is comming

[image]

any idea how i can call this in templates to show the carousel with the text and image .

currently this is returning the  @Umbraco.Field("car")

whole object any suggestions please , i needs to display as a carousel :)

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field to give solution for your question, But I can say that this is not the correct way of asking question here. you have to be more specific about the issue not about the history/story and show the code instead for screen shots

Comment: if you know umbraco u willunderstand if not its difficult to explain :)  @un-lucky

Answer (score 1):

As far as Umbraco is concerned it is giving you the raw value that is contained in the property, you need to either parse the raw value or my recommended approach would be to implement your own [PropertyValueConvertor](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/property-editors/value-converters)

> A property value converter converts a property editors database stored value to another type. The converted value can be accessed from MVC Razor or any other Published Content API.

To achieve this you will want to implement the `IPropertyValueConverter` interface.

There are lots of examples around to demonstrate how to implement on of your own. Here is one nice simple but relevant [example](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Core/PropertyEditors/ValueConverters/JsonValueConverter.cs) taken from the Umbraco Core:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent;

namespace Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The default converter for all property editors that expose a JSON value type
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Since this is a default (umbraco) converter it will be ignored if another converter found conflicts with this one.
    /// </remarks>
    [DefaultPropertyValueConverter]
    [PropertyValueType(typeof(JToken))]
    [PropertyValueCache(PropertyCacheValue.All, PropertyCacheLevel.Content)]
    public class JsonValueConverter : PropertyValueConverterBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// It is a converter for any value type that is "JSON"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyType"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool IsConverter(PublishedPropertyType propertyType)
        {
            var propertyEditor = PropertyEditorResolver.Current.GetByAlias(propertyType.PropertyEditorAlias);
            if (propertyEditor == null) return false;
            return propertyEditor.ValueEditor.ValueType.InvariantEquals(PropertyEditorValueTypes.Json);
        }

        public override object ConvertDataToSource(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
        {
            if (source == null) return null;
            var sourceString = source.ToString();

            if (sourceString.DetectIsJson())
            {
                try
                {
                    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sourceString);
                    return obj;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.Error<JsonValueConverter>("Could not parse the string " + sourceString + " to a json object", ex);                    
                }
            }

            //it's not json, just return the string
            return sourceString;
        }

        //TODO: Now to convert that to XPath!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing some HTML and Razor to get some results. You'll need Bootstrap installed for the following:

```
<section class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            @foreach (var slide in CurrentPage.Car)
            {
               if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slide))
               {
                  continue;
               }

                <div class="item @(slide == CurrentPage.Car[0] ? "active" : string.Empty)">
                    <div class="fullwidth-block full-screen">
                        <img src="@Umbraco.Media(slide.img).Url" class="fill">

                        <div>
                           @slide.desc
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This works on Umbraco 7.5.13. You may need to do a bit of debugging to get this working in your scenario. However judging by your screenshot, do you only use the backoffice? Not Visual Studio etc.